# Why i can't add libraries to my Java project in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm trying to add MySQL Jconnector to my project, I downloaded this [source code](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-video-recording) and i want to add MySQL support to do register/login options but i can't add the jar file since i can't find libraries tap in project properties ! i only have this folders and i can't add new folders or remove any of them :

[image]

project properties window :

[image]

Any help please ?

Comment: change to files view, you are currently under project view.

Comment: Also i can't and i have other projects and i can use and see the libraries

Comment: You're using a maven based project, so you can only add libraries from maven. If you have the source, you might be able to add the source directory to the "Sources" otherwise, right click the dependencies node and add a dependency and try and search for the library your want to use

Comment: Preferably, right click the Dependencies node, select "Add Dependency" and do a search for the library you want to  add

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer that's what i needed it's works great :)

Comment: I did some digging and found a satisfying solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62796660/netbeans-12-doesnt-manage-libraries-anymore)