# NetBeans 12 doesn't manage libraries anymore

Tags: java, netbeans

A week ago I upgraded my Java IDE to Netbeans 12 (and JDK 14), and only yesterday I noticed the window Project Properties (MYPROG) lacks of essential functionality i.e. there are not lines for compiling in `*.jar`, and mostly there is not any line for adding `*.jar` libraries, there is instead an empty line for `JavaScript` libraries, and it is impossible to add them in any other point.

The real oddity of NetBeans 12 is that it works perfectly even with old projects made with NetBeans 8 and JDK6! but reinstalling previous NetBeans 10 still remaisn a trouble.
I'm stuck making new projects that need libraries.
Minor problems are: `System.err.println` doesn't write in red colour, the path `src/mycode` has become `src/main/java/mycode`, why? and perhaps many others.
My attempts are over.
I've installed

- OS: Window 10
- jdk-14_window-x64_bin.exe
- Apache NetBeans 12 LTS
- Binaries: netbeans-12.0-bin.zip (SHA-512, PGP ASC) 1st try
- Installers: Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-windows-x64.exe (SHA-512, PGP ASC) 2nd try.

It's a Java project using Maven

I don't know Gradle and Ant (what are they for?)

- Project Properties (MYPROG)-->Build has only Compile without Compiling, Packaging, Deployment, Documenting
- Project Properties (MYPROG)--> Libraries does not exist
  instead: JavaScript libraries (empty)

Answer (score 5):

When you are using Maven, the Project properties do not have a Libraries section, because the libraries are managed through Maven (and not NetBeans).

You manage the needed libraries through the "Dependencies" node of the project or by editing `pom.xml` directly:

[image]

But this has been the case since NetBeans started supporting Maven (so probably 8.0 or something along those lines). If you had a "Libraries" section in the project properties before, you were using an Ant based project.

> *path `src/mycode` has become `src/main/java/mycode`, why?*

Because `src/main/java` is the default directory layout Maven uses.

Answer (score 3):

If you recreate the project as Ant project, you will have the option to import library in the project properties.

[Netbeans Java project with Ant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZlxn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).